# Why I can't redirect subdomain from htaccess while having Cloudflare?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, cloudflare

Why I can't redirect subdomain from htaccess while using CloudFlare SSL?

PS I don't know if I can paste URL here so I **won't** paste it to avoid removal of the question.

I'm getting this problem in Chrome (but it doesn't work in Firefox either)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU0qt.png)

I know there are fixes on the internet for this error but none worked for me. Is it because I have root domain connected to CloudFlare (also affects subdomains)?

What I did is:
1. created a subdomain in hosting and set its file directory.
2. in that file directory made .htaccess file.
3. inside the file

```
Redirect 301 / https://rootdomain/firstfolder
```

but it falls into redirects loop :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With my .htaccess code, I check if the domain has the www. dub on the domain, then I redirect it to the subdomain without the www. dub on it. Also, because I don't think you want to change it, I place a 301 Redirect on it also.

I forgot to mention, usually people do not use the www. on the subdomain also, so I am guessing that you don't want people to use it either.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/sundomain\.domain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

For specific url : put below code in your subdomain.domain.com's .htacess

```
Redirect 301 /blue-car/ http://www.example.com/cars/red-car
```

Comment: Hey mate thanks for answer but is there any way to redirect specific urls rather than rewrite everything? for example subdomain.domain.com/blue-car/   redirect to    domain.com/cars/red-car

Comment: check the code  Redirect 301 /blue-car/ http://www.example.com/cars/red-car do not put the space between http://  www.example.com/cars/red-car  i have given space because of stack overflow do not allow http link

Comment: I cant upvote. Dont know if tis working because hosting is not allowing me to add the same subdomain i had before (i removed it in the fervor of testing and looking for solution) ... Anyway thakn you